# A.N.T generator noise settings

Tags: add-on, procedural

The A.N.T generator has a huge set of noise options

- 19 noise types
- 10 noise bases

So if I want a particular kind of landscape (mountains, fells) how to properly set noise type and basis. Is the proper choice only based on aesthetics.